# Internet connected problem wsl 2 ubuntu 22.04 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, connection

Recently I installed WSL 2 Ubuntu 22.04 on my Windows 10 machine, but nothing seems to work properly, because I have no internet access.
I tried a few commands and sudo apt update says 'Connection failed' and ping google.com
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎06/‎02/‎2023
OS build    19044.2486
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

```
~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You say you have no internet access. Does the host Windows machine have internet access?

Comment: Yes I can access the internet on the windows side

Comment: Ok, I would shutdown wsl, and start it again. `wsl --shutdown`

Comment: I have tried wsl --shutdown but that didn't fix anything

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while trying to run `brew update`. Solved it by configuring the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Run `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`.

**The original file should look like this:**

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
# nameserver 127.x.x.x
```

**Change it to this:**

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now save the changes `CTRL O` `ENTER` `CTRL X` and test if your network is working again `nslookup askubuntu.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue on Windows 10 after not using WSL2 for a while on my laptop. No internet access whatsoever.

Restarting wsl `wsl --shutdown` or changing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file did not fix the issue, neither did installing a different version of Ubuntu and running that in wsl.

For me I somehow fixed the issue by installing the `Windows 10, version 22H2` update and restarting my laptop. Suddenly I have internet again. I'm not sure what version I was on before, but for anybody encountering this issue not on `version 22H2` I suggest updating to that and rebooting your PC.